# Drawing two tables such that one table contains a picture

Tags: tables, picture-mode

I'm using this template in my exams.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

%########### PREAMBULE #####################

%Choix math\'ematiques
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\linespread{1.2}

%%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.cm,right=1.cm,top=0.6cm,bottom=1.5cm}


% Choix de la langue
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

%Choix de formatage: INDEX
\usepackage{makeidx}

%%\usepackage{first,french}[draftcopy]

%%Insertion de figure
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}

%Style de la bibliographie
\bibliographystyle{plain}

% Pour XY-pic
\usepackage[all]{xy}



\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Th\'eor\`eme}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemme}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{col}[theorem]{Corollaire}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{D\'efinition}
\newtheorem{remark}{ Remarque}
\newtheorem{exemple}{\bf Exemple\/}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\DD}{\mathbb D}
\newcommand{\TT}{\mathbb T}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\cqfd}
%\newcommand{Y}{>{\itshape\raggedright}X}
%\newcommand{Y}{>{\itshape\raggedleft}X}
{%
 \mbox{}%
 \nolinebreak%
 \hfill%
 \rule{2mm}{2mm}%
 %%medbreak%
 \par%
 }
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{fancy} %%\lhead{Cours Algèbre T.1 - ..... }
%%%\chead{\textbf{Introduction générale}}
%\fancyfoot[R]{contenu} %\lhead{\textbf{Chapitre 1: Notions de
%logique }} \rhead{\textbf{A.U: 2017/2018}}
  \lfoot{\textbf{Examen d'Algèbre N°1 - Techno. 1 - 12 Janvier 2021} } %\rfoot{\textbf{Page 1/2 }}
%%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.7pt}
%%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.7pt}
%%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}
%%\fancyhead[L]{\LaTeX \quad C'est super!} \fancyhead[R]{Académie de
%%Poitiers}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{3pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
%fin
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}





\begin{flushright}
\vskip 2 cm  {\large\ding{95}} {\large\ding{95}}
\emph{\textbf{\underline{Bon travail}}} {\large\ding{95}}
{\large\ding{95}}
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

> I want to add in the top of the page the following two tables with the Logo of my Faculty like this

[image]

Comment: Your MWE is not related to showed picture. That we can reproduce it,  we need to rewrite tables from scratch (what is not fun) . So, please be so kind, and provide code for content of the  left and right table. Also, please remove in your MWE all what is not related to tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using nested tabulars that could serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{10.4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{10.4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|@{}c@{}|c|@{}c@{}|}
  \cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    text \\
    text \\
    text \\
    text \\
    text \\
    text \\
    text\\
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}\\
  \end{tabular}
  & &
  \begin{tabular}{0l|p{4cm}}
    text & \\ \hline
    text & \\ \hline
    text & \\ \hline
    text & \\ \hline
    text & \\ \hline
    text & \\ 
  \end{tabular}\\
  \cline{1-1}  \cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```